# Unity WWW cancel request and close socket/connection

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the latest (4.5.4) version of Unity3D, is it possible to cancel a pending WWW class (HTTP) request and have it close the socket/connection?  I've tried myWWWObject.Dispose, at least in the editor play mode, and it isn't working.

[This forum post on Unity forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-stop-the-www-request.36065/) has conflicting answers.  One person says it works, then another says it doesn't but the answer they provide makes me think they only care about resuming the coroutine and not closing the actual connection.

I'm writing a game that needs to work on iOS, Android and Facebook Canvas (Web Player), and I'm using long polling to my own server.  There are times when I want to cancel an existing poll and post a new one.  In some cases (kind of odd behavior but possible) the user could cause that to happen over and over many times in a row.  I don't want all of those connections to stay open on my server, or client side, even though it is easy for my code to ignore any result/response.

I can probably work around this with design changes, but would rather not, if there is a robust way to close/cancel/abort/stop the request.  I'm pretty sure all of the 3 platforms I need to support have ways to do this natively, but not sure I want to use native plugins instead of WWW class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure but I think that when you mean to close the socket connection you are lowering down to the TCP/IP or UDP layer.  Then, you are not in control of this layer from a WWW gameObject as far as I know.  So technically even if you cancel out the 'transfer', the socket will have to wait for a TCP/IP timeout to be dropped by the OS...  I think...

I found this link that might shed some light at your particular issue: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/676443/wwwdispose-doesnt-work.html

Still I think that .Dispose() might still not close the actual socket like you want.  Only in the case that you are directly handling via Thread, TcpListener and TcpClient you are allowed to issue an actual socket close().

Like for example:

```
TcpListener myTcpListener;
TcpClient myTcpClient;

void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    try
    {
        myTcpClient.Close();
        isTrue = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }

    // You must close the tcp listener
    try
    {
        myTcpListener.Stop();
        isTrue = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bummer, but thanks.  I might have to research again but I don't think TcpClient works well cross platform, which is why I'm using WWW in the first place.  Maybe I'll add this as a feature request, would be nice if WWW class could support it.